# How can I add data from table to other in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 departments and created a new one, I want to update employee department but if that employees id equals one of id's listed in other table.

Employees

```
empid  empname  deptname
------------------------
01     john       dept1
02     bill       dept2
03     alex       dept1
.
.
.
80     tomas      dept1
```

New_depts_employees_id

```
empid
-----
02
05
45
18
20
34
78
80
55
32
```

If employee's id is inside the second table his depname will become 'dept3'

How can I write code make this process in SQL language (I using MS Access).

Comment: Is you are using Microsoft Access tag that, not 2 other completely different RDBMS. Don't tag spam, only tag things that are related to your question.

Comment: You are looking for the query in SQL ?

Comment: Im sorry its my first question i dont understand the rules well

Comment: Maybe [`INSERT... SELECT...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql) may help you?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want sql? You can use `update` and `exists` as follows:

```
Update employees
   Set dept_name = 'dept3'
 Where exists (select 1 from New_depts_employees_id n where n.emp_id = employees.emp_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open new query constructor.

Add both tables to it.

Drag `Employees.empid` and drop it onto `New_depts_employees_id.empid` - a link occures. Not needed if the link is created automatically.

Change query type to UPDATE.

Set "Column to update" to `Employees.deptname`.

Set "Value to set" to `'dept3'`.

Click "Execute".

---

You may save this query and convert static `'dept3'` value to query parameter for future use from external application. Or you may open query constructor in SQL Mode and copy query text from it for external use.